# Apache Virtual Hosts setting IP, subfolders and domain separately

Tags: apache, server, virtualhost, digital-ocean

I have the following problem:
I was using my VPS (digitalocean) only by IP and had a few pages being acessible as Alias like this:
123.321.456.654/page1, 123.321.456.654/page2, etc.

Now I need to host a website with a domain from a domainhoster and still want to use my directories via IP.

I found tutorials, for how to set up multiple domains, but not how to leave the IP itself as a separate directory. At the moment I have a *.conf* file in my *sites-enabled* directory titled like the domain name.
The domain is linked to a sub-folder /var/www/officialpage.

Now if I want the domain to be linked properly, I have to disable the *default-000.conf* file, but then I loose all my other Aliases.

How can I setup my domain to be treated like an Alias, and make the IP itself point to another page? Is it possible at all?

here are my .conf files

**domain.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName domain.com
        ServerAlias www.domain.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/page4

        <Directory /var/www/raum4>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**and my 000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        Alias /page1 /var/www/p1
        Alias /page2 /var/www/p2
        Alias /page3 /var/www/p3

        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you show your VirtualHost config?

Comment: If you have both enabled, what happens (i.e. which page is shown in the browser) when you request your `domain.com` and what happens when you request the IP pages?

Comment: When I request domain, I get the content of /var/www/html, when I enter the IP, I get the same.. When requesting IP/page4, I get page4.. another strange thing is, that I only get the IP address in the browser address bar, somehow I'm being forwarded

Comment: Did you enable your domain.com.conf like this: `a2ensite domain.com.conf`?

Comment: yes both files are enabled: 000-default and domain.com

Answer (score 0):

2 Days later everything works as it should.. seems like my provider needs more than the 6 hours he's claiming to set up everything. still thank you!